How do I deal with Cloudflared docker container error
I wanted to update my cloudflared docker container and this is what I get now. What do I do?
2024-05-10T07:11:09Z INF Starting tunnel tunnelID=EDITED
2024-05-10T07:11:09Z INF Version 2024.4.1
2024-05-10T07:11:09Z INF GOOS: linux, GOVersion: go1.21.5-devel-cf, GoArch: amd64
2024-05-10T07:11:09Z INF Settings: map[no-autoupdate:true token:*****]
2024-05-10T07:11:09Z INF Generated Connector ID: EDITED
2024-05-10T07:11:09Z INF Initial protocol quic
2024-05-10T07:11:09Z INF ICMP proxy will use 172.17.0.3 as source for IPv4
2024-05-10T07:11:09Z INF ICMP proxy will use :: as source for IPv6
2024-05-10T07:11:09Z WRN The user running cloudflared process has a GID (group ID) that is not within ping_group_range. You might need to add that user to a group within that range, or instead update the range to encompass a group the user is already in by modifying /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ping_group_range. Otherwise cloudflared will not be able to ping this network error="Group ID 65532 is not between ping group 1 to 0"
2024-05-10T07:11:09Z WRN ICMP proxy feature is disabled error="cannot create ICMPv4 proxy: Group ID 65532 is not between ping group 1 to 0 nor ICMPv6 proxy: socket: permission denied"
2024-05-10T07:11:09Z INF Starting metrics server on 127.0.0.1:33081/metrics
2024/05/10 07:11:09 failed to sufficiently increase receive buffer size (was: 208 kiB, wanted: 2048 kiB, got: 416 kiB). See https://github.com/quic-go/quic-go/wiki/UDP-Buffer-Sizes for details.
2024-05-10T07:11:09Z ERR Failed to serve quic connection error="failed to accept QUIC stream: INTERNAL_ERROR (local): write udp [::]:49307->198.41.200.113:7844: sendmsg: cannot allocate memory" connIndex=0 event=0 ip=198.41.200.113
2024-05-10T07:11:09Z ERR Serve tunnel error error="failed to accept QUIC stream: INTERNAL_ERROR (local): write udp [::]:49307->198.41.200.113:7844: sendmsg: cannot allocate memory" connIndex=0 event=0 ip=198.41.200.113
2024-05-10T07:11:09Z INF Retrying connection in up to 2s connIndex=0 event=0 ip=198.41.200.113
2024-05-10T07:11:09Z INF Tunnel server stopped
2024-05-10T07:11:09Z ERR Initiating shutdown error="failed to accept QUIC stream: INTERNAL_ERROR (local): write udp [::]:49307->198.41.200.113:7844: sendmsg: cannot allocate memory"
2024-05-10T07:11:09Z INF Metrics server stopped
failed to accept QUIC stream: INTERNAL_ERROR (local): write udp [::]:49307->198.41.200.113:7844: sendmsg: cannot allocate memory

I've tried creating a new container but the same error shows up.

Check the above logs, there are some warnings ("WRN") that I'd try to find out what they mean. Just use the search field above. Barring that, provide a [mcve], because "wanted to update" is far from enough info to reproduce anything. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Today was the first time that I tried to update this particular container since I've had it (and it worked fine up till today). I simply pulled the latest version in portainer as I always update my containers this way. Unfortunately this ended up the way you see above. I cannot find any info about the WRNs and Errors above.
